# Authentication issues for GitHub api request

Tags: git, curl, github, github-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of collaborators from a repository on GitHub, as an example, I am using the repository of the GitHub API for Golang.

In curl, the request would be the following:

```
curl -u "my user" https://api.github.com/repos/google/go-github/collaborators
```

After a password prompt, I get the following JSON result:

```
{
  "message": "Must have push access to view repository collaborators.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

How do I get push access? Do I need to become a collaborator myself? A bit too much just to get a list of a project's contributors.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/

Looks like it. I don't think you can do much to get around this. Weird.

Comment: Do you want to get a project's *collaborators* or their *contributors*? They're different. Contributors are anyone who's had a commit accepted, that is public information in the Git repository itself. The collaborators are the project administrators, that information is private.

Comment: @Schwern I need the contributors. EDIT - just tested it out. Works! Put up an answer, so I can give you a check mark!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I get push access? Do I need to become a collaborator myself? A bit too much just to get ***a list of a project's contributors***.

A project's collaborators and contributors are different.

Contributors are anyone who's had a commit accepted, that is public information on the project web page and from running `git log`.  [You can get project contributors from the Github API without logging in](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors).

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/google/go-github/contributors | head -20
[
  {
    "login": "willnorris",
    "id": 1112,
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1112?v=3",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/willnorris",
```

Collaborators are the project administrators on Github, that information is private.